# Having trouble with a React project other group members can compile and it works correctly

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-hooks, package, single-page-application

Hello this is the error I get.

caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
at Books (books.js:51:1)
at renderWithHooks

```
   <div className="book-list">
                 (line 51)  {books.data.map((book) => (
                        <NavLink key={book.book_id} className={({isActive}) => isActive ? "active" : ""} to={`/books/${book.book_id}`} >
                            <span>&nbsp;</span>
                            <div>{book.title}</div>
                        </NavLink>
                        ))}
                </div>
```

I have tried updating my npm files and reinstalling, but no joy. The other members of my school group aren't having this problem on their end and we can't seem to find a work around, even though we are pulling from the same GIT source!

Rest of the pages on our site display fine for me, but for some reasons, the books page does not. Here is the complete code for that page.

```
import {settings} from "../../config/config";
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {NavLink, useLocation, Outlet} from "react-router-dom";
import './book.css';
import useXmlHttp from "../../services/useXmlHttp";
import {useAuth} from "../../services/useAuth";
import Pagination from "./pagination";

import React from 'react';

const Books = () => {

    const {user} = useAuth();
    const {pathname} = useLocation();
    const [subHeading, setSubHeading] = useState("All Books");
    //const url = settings.baseApiUrl + "/books";
    const [url, setUrl] = useState(settings.baseApiUrl + "/books");

    const {
        error,
        isLoading,
        data: books
    } = useXmlHttp(url, "GET", {Authorization: `Bearer ${user.jwt}`});

    useEffect(() => {
        setSubHeading("All Books");
    }, [pathname]);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="main-heading">
                <div className="container">Book</div>
            </div>
            <div className="sub-heading">
                <div className="container">{subHeading}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="main-content container">

                {error && <div>{error}</div>}
                {isLoading && <div className="image-loading">
                    <img src={require(`../loading.gif`)} alt="Loading ......"/>
                    </div>}
                {books && <div className="book-container">
                    <div className="book-list">
                        {books.data.map((book) => (
                            <NavLink key={book.book_id} className={({isActive}) => isActive ? "active" : ""} to={`/books/${book.book_id}`} >
                                <span>&nbsp;</span>
                                <div>{book.title}</div>
                            </NavLink>
                            ))}
                    </div>

                    <div className="book-item">
                        {books && <Pagination books={books} setUrl={setUrl}/>}
                        <Outlet context={[subHeading, setSubHeading]} />
                    </div>
                </div>}
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Books;
```

Super frustrating, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a data problem. The people encountering this error have a truthy value for `books`, but `books` does not have a `.data` field.

Log `books` to see what the data actually is.